# Delete list elements after using them

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, iterator

I have a list

```
test_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to iterate over the elements of this list and delete them after using. But when I try to do this

```
for element in test_list:
    print element
    test_list.remove(element)
```

Alternate elements  are printed and removed from `test_list`

```
1
3
5
print test_list
[2, 4]
```

Please explain why this happens!

Comment: Look at the "Related" list. You will find several duplicates with answers.

Comment: Repeat after me: Don't modify things while you're iterating over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the answers to *[strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list)* to understand why this is happening.

If you really need to modify your list while iterating do this:

```
>>> items = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> while items:
...     item = items.pop()
...     print item
...
z
y
x
>>> items
[]
```

Note that this will iterate in reverse order.

Comment: a way to iterate in the initial order would just be calling test_list.reverse() before running the loop

Answer (score 1):

in python this concept is called an iterator

```
my_iter = iter(my_list)
```

each time you consume or look at an element it becomes gone ...